# Is there a way to make an app that splits the desktop screen?

Tags: windows-vista, desktop, multiple-instances

Is there a way that I can split screen the desktop so I can run one program in one side and another on the other side? I want to be able to run 2 games at the same time and play them both without having to ALT+TAB to switch.

Comment: Double boxing on 1 screen?

Comment: If  you have windows 7, Windows Key + Left Arrow/Right Arrow will dock to left and right side of screen. Your aspect ratio for the games are going to be all over the shop though.

Comment: I hope, we can't focused on two windows @ same time. I also looking ans for this Q?

Comment: only windows 7 has this feature? I have vista.

Comment: no no need to have focus on both at the same time.

Comment: Perhaps this question belongs to SuperUser.com as you are looking for an application more than a way to build that application. Also take a look at Acer GridVista (free to download)

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.autohotkey.com?

Comment: the win + arrow keys only work on windowed applications.

Comment: Next time please specify the OS you're talking about, thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about full screen DirectX games of some kind? Some games let you toggle between full screen and windowed, often with Alt+Enter.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest on your game, you look in options and try to either enable `Windowed mode` or disable `Full Screen Mode`, you can then select the resolution most applicable to your screen resolution so you can display two windows at once.

That being said, you will still need to either <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or similar to actually switch the focus, but, based on comments, I assume you are talking about not Alt-tabbing through full screen applications.

Comment: Yeah I guess that would work William Hilsum thanks all. I have one more question by the way, is there a way to enlarge the screens displayed in the ALT+TAB menu and also keep it on the screen without having to hold ALT+TAB?

Comment: Not really, Alt tab isn't really configurable. There are replacements, but, I haven't looked at this area since the Windows XP Powertool that I doubt works on Windows Vista/7.  You may want to try Windows Key + Tab or actually click on the Windows Vista program switch icon near the bottom which should do the same, but keep it in focus.... http://imgur.com/tJ1dR